# Non Updatable column in mysql table

Tags: mysql

How to define a mysql table that should have one column as non updatable I mean once inserted it should not allow user to update in any way. 
For Example table named tbl_xyz have 3 columns where one is non updatable then 
tbl_xyz(c1,c2,c3), suppose I Insert values as (MBX,123,POQ) then lets say if c3 is non updatable then it should be always have value with first entry as POQ if some one tries to update then it should give some constrained column specific error.

If someone have did same table level defination with above mentioned restriction then please help and let me know please.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done via a [trigger](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html) in MySQL:

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE TRIGGER `trig_tbl_xyz_before_update`
BEFORE UPDATE ON `tbl_xyz` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF NEW.c3 != OLD.c3 THEN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
      SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'tbl_xyz.c3 is not allowed to be updated, stop trying to update it.';
  END IF;
END;;
DELIMITER ;
```

This will give the following response when trying to update `tbl_xyz.c3` to a different value:

> Error Code: 1644. tbl_xyz.c3 is not allowed to be updated, stop trying to update it.

I used the **45000** error code because it was suggested in the [SIGNAL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/signal.html) documentation.

> To signal a generic SQLSTATE value, use '45000', which means “unhandled user-defined exception.”

Answer (score 3):

I am not very expert in MySQL but I guess By Sever, you can apply such restrictions.Just Remove update permissions to that column from your user. You can do this by famous MySQL [Grant](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html) query
 [here is the Update Grant Section](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_update)

Answer (score 1):

You can try the code on this forum ([link](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?195114-how-to-set-a-column-NOT-Updateable)).. I jusy looked it up on google and that is what I've found.