# Way to make a specific column or row column value unchangeable?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

Using MySQL 5.6.

I'm writing a function that updates a database, and then after checks to make sure the data was written correctly.

With what I am testing this on, it's always written so fast that there's never a chance for error.

I want to know if there's a way to make a specific column immutable essentially, so that the update function runs, MySQL will reject that column or the query wholesale is fine as well, so that my check function does have a discrepancy to pick up on.

Is there a way to do this in MySQL 5.6 and if so how?

Comment: Unclear to your exact intent, but you could check if the data was written correctly with a MySQL trigger, if not the trigger could throw an exception you can catch. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31225195/non-updatable-column-in-mysql-table/51804788#51804788

Comment: I want to make a column immutable essentially so that updates on it don't do anything or get rejected so that I could test the checking function that runs after my updates/inserts.

Comment: Nothing out of the box I can think of. You could add another column to the table called `Immutable` have the trigger check if `Immutable` is true and either not update the column or throw an error. After you're done running your checking function, set `Immutable` to false so the column can again be updated. This should work.

Comment: Yea that's a decent idea I can make work.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Revert in trigger.

```
CREATE TRIGGER reject_update
BEFORE UPDATE
ON tablename
FOR EACH ROW
SET NEW.fieldname = OLD.fieldname;
```