# How to set current date when creating a new record and then maintaining (not updating) this date

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, sql-server-2008-r2, default

In my database (MS-SQL 2008 R2) I want to add the current date automatically to the according field when a record is added. I found out how to enter the formula for the default value (I used GETDATE()), but default setting for formulas is "is consistant" = false. When I try to change that to true I get the error message "cannot be persisted because the column is non-deterministic." when trying to save the changes.

I tried to change the column to deterministic but that also resulted in an error, which is explained on a microsoft page, but on that page I also read that all functions with a similiar purpose are non-deterministic. So is it not possible to set a default date when creating the record and after that maintaining the value?

Without being able to change the consistancy to true, all entries of this column are permanently updated and the original value is not saved in the database. Like that the calculation is absolutely useless.

Does anyone know how to be able to set the current date to a field when creating a new record and maintaining that record then?

Thanks

Susanne

Comment: You could add a trigger on record inserts to set the current date.

Comment: Check this out: [Non Updatable column in mysql table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31225195/non-updatable-column-in-mysql-table)

Comment: "Persisted" is an attribute for a computed column. You don't have a computed column, you have (or need) a "regular" column that has the default of GETDATE().

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are describing.  You can define a column with a default value and then use that value for an index:

```
create table t (
     t_id int identity primary key,
     x int,
     created_at datetime default getdate()
);

create index idx_t_created_at on t(created_at);
```

You cannot do this with a computed column.  However, you specifically do not want a computed column to capture the creation datetime.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=83786ab34b5f7bdc106d8a82d5701b06) is a db<>fiddle.  It uses a later version of SQL Server, but I don't think this functionality has changed since 2008.